How to subscribe efficiently to multiple account using websockets
I would like to subscribe to multiple accounts using websockets. The example provided by the documentation show only the subscription to a log (which is fine) but with only one account.
Basically, I can call multiple times the following method:
await ws.account_subscribe(pkey)

But then I need to retrieve the subscription identifier like the following:
reply = await ws.recv()
reply[0].result

However, if I loop on account_subscribe how can I ensure the identifier from recv() will come in correct order ?
Thank you.

You can use the function on onAccountChange from the connection class like so:
const subscriptionId = connection.onAccountChange(
      globalLevel1GameDataPDA,
      (accountInfo) => {
        const decoded = program.coder.accounts.decode(
          "gameDataAccount",
          accountInfo.data
        )
        console.log("New player position via socket", decoded.playerPosition)
        setGameDataAccount(decoded)
      }
    )

Here is an example react app:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples/blob/main/tiny-adventure/app/pages/index.tsx
And some docs:
https://solana.com/de/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe
https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/accountSubscribe
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange
Edit:
Oh looks like you are using python?
Then you may need to keep track of the subscription id and save a callback for each and when you get a new message look at your subscriptions. Here is a C# implementation of that logic, maybe that helps?
https://github.com/Woody4618/SolPlay_Unity_SDK/blob/main/Assets/SolPlay/Scripts/Services/SolPlayWebSocketService.cs
The logic should be similar. This is the RPC call definition:
https://solana.com/de/docs/rpc/websocket/accountsubscribe
Or maybe check github if someone wrote that already.

Thank you for your answer so basically, I already subscribe to multiple account. Just by calling multiple times await ws.account_subscribe(pkey) with a different public key. And after those calls, I call await ws.recv() in a loop so I retrieve the subscription identifier. But I'm not sure if I got it in the right order. But anyway, everything works, I will see later if it cause any issue.

Good luck! Let me know if it doesnt work out. They will probably come in the order in which they change

It seems to work. In fact, await ws.recv() give the reply in order. Thank you !
